# Openstack/Packstack Services

Tags: openstack

I am currently new with OpenStack/packstack, I have successfully installed it on Centos 7 (VM). But when I turn off and power on the VM again, I need to have to repeat the long installation process of packstack. I need to run this specific code `packstack --answer-file 24.01.19.conf` in order for me to access the Openstack Web Interface. I tried running `openstack-service restart|start|stop|status` but this causes an error "command not found". Any other way around to access the web interface without running the packstack --answer-file every time I start my VM? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To use openstack-service, install "openstack-utils"

```
sudo yum install -y openstack-utils
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the IP address of controller node changes after reboot and if IP address changes you need to re-run the packstack.

My recommendation is to statically bind the IP address to the VM where the packstack is running.

Link to bind IP address to VM/Mac in KVM: [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-kvm-libvirt-dnsmasq-dhcp-static-ip-address-configuration-for-guest-os/)!